# How to create LazyLoad es6 class correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, es6-class

I use this code to lazy load images - https://jsbin.com/bozulobina/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
function lazyLoad() {

  const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  const imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        let image = entry.target;
        image.src = image.dataset.src;
        image.classList.remove("lazy");
        imageObserver.unobserve(image);
      }
    });
  });

  lazyImages.forEach(image => {
    imageObserver.observe(image)
  });

}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', lazyLoad);
```

Trying to rewrite this code using Class es6 - https://jsbin.com/rejurobupa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
class LazyLoad{
  constructor(imgElement){
    this.imgElement = imgElement;
    this.interObserver()
  }
  interObserver() {
    const imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((images, options) => {
      images.forEach(image => {
        if (image.isIntersecting) {
          let imageLazy = image.target;
          imageLazy.src = imageLazy.dataset.src;
          imageLazy.classList.remove(this.imgElement);
          imageObserver.unobserve(imageLazy);
        }
      });
    });

    lazyImages.forEach(image => imageObserver.observe(image));
  }  

}
const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");
const lazyLoad = new LazyLoad(lazyImages);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', lazyLoad);
```

Tell me how to do it right, and where do I make mistakes?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just remove the line imageLazy.classList.remove(this.imgElement); from your code.

Comment: Fixed it, check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5ohn6gzr/6/

Comment: "*Trying to rewrite this code using Class es6*" - why?! There are no objects created in your original code, you're not even having any state to keep that you could structure in objects. Do not use `class` syntax here!

Answer (score 0):

I updated the answer. The corrections are:

- Set height and width on img elements
- Call the LazyLoad constructor on DOMContentLoaded

```js
class LazyLoad{
  constructor( imgClass ) {
    this.imgClass = imgClass;
    this.imgElement = document.querySelectorAll(imgClass);    
    this.interObserver();
  }
  interObserver() {
    const imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((images, options) => {
      images.forEach(image => {
        if (image.isIntersecting) {
          let imageLazy = image.target;
          imageLazy.src = imageLazy.dataset.src;
          imageLazy.classList.remove(this.imgClass);
          imageObserver.unobserve(imageLazy);
        }
      });
    });
  
    this.imgElement.forEach(image => imageObserver.observe(image));
  }    
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', new LazyLoad(".lazy-img"));
```

```css
img{
  display: block;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/arch" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/people" alt="">

<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/arch" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/people" alt="">

<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/arch" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature" alt="">
<img src="#" class="lazy-img" data-src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/people" alt="">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the links to the image in src is added immediately to all images.This should happen as you scroll.

Comment: Oh.got it. Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: The  images were loading immediately  becasue you have not specified any width and height for the image elements initially. So it thinks all the images are inside the viewport any away which leads to "image.isIntersecting" true for all the images on page load.  I fixed it, here is the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5ohn6gzr/6/

Comment: This doesn't work properly: you don't want to call the `document.querySelectorAll("img")` before the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired. If you don't care because your script is placed at the bottom of the document, you should stop using the `DOMContentLoaded` event entirely.

Comment: @Bergi - Good point, thanks. I edited the code in snippet.  here is fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/x184gvfz/2/. I think it would be better to not rely on the placement of the script.